# Tutorial about key mapping in KSH in EMACS mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aix, ksh

Are there any good tutorials to learn about key-mapping in Korn Shell (AIX) in EMACS mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O'Reilly's *Learning the Korn Shell* has an outstanding reference for using emacs.  I own a couple of copies (paper and online) but have found it is always available somewhere in PDF from Google as a top listing.